# OnClick for mapbox Layer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I am using `react-map-gl` to add a map to my React app. I want to add an `onClick` event to my `Layer` component, but it looks like `react-map-gl` does not support it. (docs here: https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/layer )

I've recently discovered that `react-mapbox-gl` does support `onClick` events for `Layer` components, but I am having trouble installing it through `npm` (tree dependency issues).

I was wondering if anyone here has managed to add the `onClick` event using `react-map-gl`? Any advice?

Example code below:

```
import React from "react";
import { Layer, LayerProps } from "react-map-gl";

export const MapLayer: React.FunctionComponent<LayerProps> = ({
  id,
  type,
  paint,
  source,
  layout,
}) => {
  return (
    <Layer id={id} type={type} paint={paint} source={source} layout={layout} />
  );
};
```

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Not sure what you need to do with the onClick, but there are interactive examples here http://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/examples.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `react-map-gl` would definitely **support** `onClick` event.

However, the event is not designed to respond to each individual layer, instead it comes under the default `Map` component. You will need to specify the `interactiveLayerIds` property to make it work on specific layers.

Please refer to the section of [onClick event](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/map#onclick) from `react-map-gl` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your handleClick function, with the layer id you want to react to

```
const feature = event.features.find((f) => f.layer.id === "routeId");
```